# Embedding base64 encoded Java-Applet in HTML

Tags: html, debugging, applet, base64, embedding

I tried to embed a base64 encoded Java-Applet in my HTML-file.
I thought I could use a data-url like in my example below:

```
<applet 
    name="AppletName"
    id="AppletId"
    code="Applet.class" 
    archive="data:application/x-jar;base64,UEsDBBQAAAAIAGY/eziUsj5wxAAAABwB...
</applet>
```

This did not work. In my tests Firefox and Chrome crashed.
I also tried different MIME types.
Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java applets aren't meant to be base64-encoded. Also, why is this tagged [tag:javascript]?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- The tag `applet` does not have the correct attribute values
- The base64 encoded data URI must be able to be decoded by a browser, not a plugin